# How to show that the rate at which the period changes with respect to temperature is kT/2?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

I have this exercise to solve:

> **Temperature and the period of a pendulum** For oscillations of small amplitude (short swings), we may safely model the relationship between the period *T* and the length *L* of a simple pendulum with the equation
>   $$
> T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}};\ \ \ (1)
> $$
>   where *g* is the constant acceleration of gravity at the pendulum’s location. If we measure *g* in centimeters per second squared, we measure *L* in centimeters and *T* in seconds. If the pendulum is made of metal, its length will vary with temperature, either increasing or decreasing at a rate that is roughly proportional to *L*. In symbols, with *u* being temperature and *k* the proportionality constant,
>   $$
> \frac{dL}{du} = kL;\ \ \ (2)
> $$
>   Assuming this to be the case, show that the rate at which the period changes with respect to temperature is $$
> k\frac{T}{2};\ \ \ (3)
> $$

Could someone, please, help with this? Any clue will be greatly appreciated.

---

#### This is what I've come to so far

Namely, I need to show that the derivative of *T* with respect to *u* is $T'(u) = k\frac{T}{2}$ or that the relation of the rate of change of the period to the period itself is $\frac{T'(u)}{T} = \frac{k}{2}$

First, I tried to find *T'(u)*, so I had to express *T* as *T(u)* and the only possible way seemed to be via relation (2): $L'(u) = kL$, that is $L = \frac{L'(u)}{k}$, then:

$$
T(u) = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}} =
2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L'(u)}{kg}}
$$

Then, by the chain rule:

$$
T'(u) = \frac{\pi * L''(u)}{\sqrt{\frac{L'(u)}{kg}}} = \sqrt{\frac{(\pi * L''(u))^2 * kg}{L'(u)}}
$$

But this seems to lead nowhere, since when I divided *T'(u)* by *T(u)* I got:

$$
\frac{T'(u)}{T(u)} = \sqrt{\frac{(\pi * L''(u))^2 * kg}{L'(u)}} : \sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2 * L'(u)}{kg}} = \\
\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2 * L''(u)^2 * (kg)^2}{L'(u)^2*4\pi^2}} = \frac{kgL''(u)}{2L'(u)}
$$

Which is definitely nowhere near the required result, i.e. relation (3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You complicated too much. Just use chain rule:
$$\begin{align}\frac {dT}{du}&=2\pi\frac1{\sqrt g}\frac d{du}\sqrt L\\&=2\pi\frac1{\sqrt{g}}\frac 1{2\sqrt L}\frac{dL}{du}\\&=2\pi\frac1{\sqrt{gL}}\frac 12 kL\\&=\frac{kT}2\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you, it didn't occur to me, that L is a function of u itself

Answer (score 2):

Take logs of both sides:
$$\ln T = \ln\left(2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}\right) = \ln 2\pi - \frac{1}{2}\ln g + \frac{1}{2}\ln L.$$
Taking derivatives with respect to $u$ gives
$$\frac{T'}{T} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{L'}{L} = \frac{kL}{2L} = \frac{k}{2}.$$

Comment: thank you, I'll look into it tomorrow, don't have time today